# Elasticsearch Nest not honoring index = not_indexed on POCO field?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i just found out through the documentation that we should be telling it to use the mapping attributes and manually creating the index before we index.

however, the documentation is not consistent with the newest version of the code. (pre release).

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html

```
var response = this.ConnectedClient.Map<ElasticSearchProject>();
```

the call above in the new code takes 1 argument in the Map() method. the documentation is not requiring any arguments.

what should be contained in that method? it seems like there are many options, but i'm unclear on which ones to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Create Indices](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/create-indices.html) documentation. I think something like this will work for what you are trying to accomplish. Plus it will create the index and apply the mapping all in one call to your Elasticsearch instance.

```cs
 client.CreateIndex("myindexname", c => c
  .NumberOfReplicas(0)
  .NumberOfShards(1)
  .Settings(s=>s
      .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor","10")
      .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
  )   
  .AddMapping<ElasticSearchProject>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
  .AddMapping<Person>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
);
```

The `.AddMapping<ElasticSearchProject>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())` line tells NEST to grab all of the Attribute settings on the via `ElasticType` and `ElasticProperty` on the ElasticSearchProject class and use those to create the mapping.

Comment: genius! i must have missed that one. worked like a charm. i removed everything but the .AddMapping part since i didn't need it. thanks.